# Wix installer. How to stop IIS pool

Tags: iis, wix, windows-installer

I faced with the problem **in my WIX installer: how can I stop specific IIS application pool during repair, change or update**?
Description: Deliver and deploy Web Application, run repair. Dialog appears that says that **w3wp** process locks files. In addition, because of requirements I cannot just hide that message and I cannot change Web Application.

[image]

What I tried to do:

1. I tried to stop service "W3SVC" with ServiceControl and it works excellent! But what I really need to do is to stop only one specific IIS pool.
2. I consider the way to write my own custom action to stop app pool, but as I know, I cannot schedule it before [InstallValidate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Please, help me overcome this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use quiet execute custom action to shell out to appcmd to stop an app pool. You are right though, you wouldn't always be elevated prior to InstallValidate.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732742(v=ws.10).aspx

I suspect this is probably a false alarm and will resolve itself later in the installer. I would look at the various was to suppress this dialog. Maybe this would help:

[WiX: Avoid showing files-in-use dialog and just prompt for reboot at end of install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981411/wix-avoid-showing-files-in-use-dialog-and-just-prompt-for-reboot-at-end-of-inst)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please accept my great thanks!

As I understand, there are just two options to overcome the issue:

1. Add <ServiceControl Id="iisServiceControl" Name="W3SVC" Start="both" Stop="both" />, in case of you agree to stop the whole service
2. Add set property<Property Id="MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL" Value="Disable" Secure="yes"
   /> and schedule your custom actions to stop/start your AppPool.

I guess to use options 2 due to the requirements. BUT, as I think, the best solution would be to say that after InstallValidate validator should just ignore some kind of processes filtering them by the name.